# Hard-coded Audio Player

Tags: theme-development, audio, flash

Continuing work today on my free theme and I'm trying to make it kick some butt.  I would like to embed an audio player into the theme.  Not a plugin, an embedded player.

The functionality of http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/ kicks some serious boo-tay.

However, that player is a bit ugly.  I do like the Woo Tumblog audio player (anybody know if I can implement this... people may make commercial themes off this theme so it needs to be legal?).  If there's a great looking player option out there that's distributable in commercial themes, simple, and well-designed let me know.

I assume I can just replace the .swf file in WP Audio Player... right?

May the force be with you.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/powerpress/ Maybe take a look through this plugin. I use it for my pdcast, but it comes with like 6 different players with varying degrees of customizability. Maybe it has what you want in it?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you have your theme require the wordpress.org version of the wpaudioplayer plugin. There is a great article about [having themes check for and require plugins](http://theme.it/how-to-display-an-admin-notice-for-required-theme-plugins/).

As is well-argued on [this WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22209/9844), it's not a great idea to take code from a plugin and include it in your theme because you miss future updates and it might be legally/morally iffy. Best of all, if a person who purchases your theme chooses to switch themes some day, all their audio players will still work and they'll be very happy and thank you forever.