# Create WordPress taxonomies based on theme settings

Tags: custom-taxonomy, actions

Is it possible to create taxonomies based on theme settings? That is, are theme settings actions run before taxonomies / post types are initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Post types and taxonomies are (should be) registered on the `init` hook. You are able to use [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) inside that hook to retrieve your theme's settings and register your post type/taxonomy with args based on those settings.

(By the way post types and taxonomies are really plug-in territory... :) )

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Regarding the plugin territory - I know it, and you're right in most of the cases. I'm not a fan of throwing everything and a kitchen sink into the theme, but once you want to create complete solution to a certain problem, that is design plus functionality then theme is the only way to go. :)

Comment: @pogoking, consider having a theme require a plugin ... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51087/9844