# How to bundle a plugin with a theme, or vice versa

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

First off, I'm all about separating design and function. In fact, I want to remove some of the functionality from a webcomics management theme I'm developing into a plugin. I expect a person's webcomic to outlast their love of a theme. This way, authors can switch themes but still retain all their uploaded comics--so long as they keep the plugin that registers those custom content types active.

However, neither the theme nor the plugin will give users *all* the functionality they need. Sure, the plugin registers your comics and your thumbnails, but only through the appropriate theme are these things displayed properly in an archive, etc.

Is there a way to bundle them so when a person activates the theme, they are prompted to install the plugin from the repository as well or it is auto-installed?

I've been looking for a solution, but so far I've only found janky zip-file bundling techniques. I'd like something a little slicker than that, that fetches the most current plugin from the repo.

Any ideas?

Comment: There has been some talk about the notion of theme-plugin dependencies, so this may be in core in the future. However it's not there yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Plugins to Wordpress Theme](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/add-plugins-to-wordpress-theme)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the following functions to build your own "theme plugins" registration:

```
is_plugin_active( $plugin );
is_plugin_active_for_network( $plugin );
is_plugin_inactive( $plugin );

get_plugins( $plugin_folder ); // register your own theme-plugins folder?
get_plugin_data( $plugin_file );
```

I use "theme plugins" myself. But not in the manner of: I have dozens of "real" plugins and then require some user to install them, but more in the fashion of: I question the existance of sub folders and register them with `current_theme_supports( 'theme-plugin-xy' )` and then include their files.