# How to add plugins to wordpress theme?

Tags: plugins, themes

I planned to develop wordpress themes commercially.. I just want to know the easy method to add plugins to my wordpress theme which I am developing.. can any one suggest me the simple steps.. and I need possible methods that I can use effectively..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Plugins to Wordpress Theme](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/add-plugins-to-wordpress-theme)

Answer (score 5):

You can always include the files of the plugins in your theme *functions.php* file. Of course you should put it into some reasonable structure to not get your theme bloated with the files and the code :).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974006/wordpress-package-plugin-with-theme
- [How to bundle a plugin with a theme, or vice versa](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27288/how-to-bundle-a-plugin-with-a-theme-or-vice-versa)

You can use code like this (used in [Carrington theme](http://carringtontheme.com/)) to load all the plugins included in the folder "plugin" within your theme folder...

```
/**
 * Load theme plugins
 * 
**/
function cfct_load_plugins() {
    $files = cfct_files(CFCT_PATH.'plugins');
    if (count($files)) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (file_exists(CFCT_PATH.'plugins/'.$file)) {
                include_once(CFCT_PATH.'plugins/'.$file);
            }
// child theme support
            if (file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH.'/plugins/'.$file)) {
                include_once(STYLESHEETPATH.'/plugins/'.$file);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Get a list of php files within a given path as well as files in corresponding child themes
 * 
 * @param sting $path Path to the directory to search
 * @return array Files within the path directory
 * 
**/
function cfct_files($path) {
    $files = apply_filters('cfct_files_'.$path, false);
    if ($files) {
        return $files;
    }
    $files = wp_cache_get('cfct_files_'.$path, 'cfct');
    if ($files) {
        return $files;
    }
    $files = array();
    $paths = array($path);
    if (STYLESHEETPATH.'/' != CFCT_PATH) {
        // load child theme files
        $paths[] = STYLESHEETPATH.'/'.str_replace(CFCT_PATH, '', $path);
    }
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        if (is_dir($path) && $handle = opendir($path)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                $path = trailingslashit($path);
                if (is_file($path.$file) && strtolower(substr($file, -4, 4)) == ".php") {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
    $files = array_unique($files);
    wp_cache_set('cfct_files_'.$path, $files, 'cfct', 3600);
    return $files;
}
```

...then you use function `cfct_load_plugins();` during the theme initialization.

Comment: "during the theme initialization" <- how can i do this?

Comment: @Anh-ThiDINH I suggest using `after_setup_theme` hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is just to use normal wordpress plugins ^^. Writing a specialized plugin system for your own theme is just totally unnecessary, makes your theme more bloated and increase development and maintaining cost. In this case the **KISS** principle wins.
Regards,
Hai

Another point to consider when replacing plug-ins with custom methods would be updates. Many plug-in updates are to address security issues, or to resolve issues caused by WordPress Updates.