# Plugin (or Theme) containing its own Plugins?

Tags: plugins, themes, customization

My Theme defines its own **actions** and **filters** so that it can be *extended* by third-parties without having to fork or modify the Theme's core code.

I already have a few plugins specific to my Theme, that I'm installing in the usual way in `wp-content/plugins` and activating through the Admin panel.

However, for ease of use, I would like to **bundle a few plugins directly into my Theme itself**, for example in `my_theme/plugins`, without having to require the user to move the plugins he wants to install to the WordPress plugin directory (thus breaking the Theme's update capabilities, etc.).

**Have you seen any Theme or Plugin that does that in an elegant way? What are best practices to  doing that?**

In particular, a few questions come to mind if I were to implement such a system:

- Is there a way to easily configure a custom plugin directory into WordPress, in addition to  `wp-content/plugins`?
- If I were to simply implement my own naive plugin activation system, what steps should I take? Do I just need to set up a basic admin panel listing, store a list of activated "custom plugins" and just include the corresponding PHP files on Theme init?

Thanks for your help!

*EDIT: Related to, but different from, [Are drop-in plugins a product of design](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20756/are-drop-in-plugins-a-product-of-design)  and [Add Plugins to Wordpress Theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/add-plugins-to-wordpress-theme): in the present case, plugins don't make sense without the Theme (they extend it) and they're written by the same person/company.*

Answer (score 3):

See [Add multiple plugin directories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43262/add-multiple-plugin-directories) for one way to do this.

In an earlier project I did something similar, but I used a dedicated theme options page for my theme plugins.
Looking back … I wouldn’t do that again. Plugin updates are a too complicated, separated version control setups too. The client wasn’t always sure where to look at when we were talking about plugins.

And sooner or later you may want to re-use a plugin from theme 1 for theme 2 – you end up copying files back and forth … far from ideal.

You can bundle multiple (single file) plugins in one directory inside the regular plugin directory. In your theme you can use [`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) to check your requirements.

TL;DR: Keep plugins and theme separate. You don’t save any work by mixing both.

Comment: Great points. I had actually seen the (impressive) answer you linked to (probably in a weekly digest mail one or two weeks ago) but had deemed it as too complicated... But it might not be that bad after all. And if I understand correctly, it may end up in core, right?

Comment: @julien_c About the core … I wouldn’t wait for it. :) It may take a looong time.

Comment: I won't be waiting for it, but it can help me decide between recoding the wheel or base my code on something that *might* one day be officially supported :)

Answer (score 1):

There's another kid on the block in this regard that's an addon for themes. It allows you create dependencies in a theme and handles guiding people through installation of the plugins you define in a nice way. The plugins don't even have to be in the WP repo.

Check it out: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Comment: I had seen that and it looks great, but I'm not sure it suits my use case: in my case, I want to include plugins but not actually activate them, unless the user explicitly activates them. They're not actually *plugin requirements$.

Comment: @julien_c Looking at the documentation you can set whether a plugin is a requirement or a recommendation by passing in `'required' => true` when you register it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've actually found (in yet [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27533/4826)) that the Carrington Theme includes bundled plugins. I'm still unsure however if this is done in the best possible way: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27533/4826